# What is this saw tooth leaved plant, and will it flower and attract bees?

Tags: identification, insects, flowering

I've got these in my garden in the city of Innsbruck, Austria and I'm wondering what they are and if their flowers attract bees or other insects. They just popped up by themselves and feel really good there, would be a shame to remove them if they attract bees/butterflies as well. If they don't,  I'd like to use the spot for something that does.

Can anyone identify them? I hope the pictures are good enough. If not, tell me and I'll try to get better ones.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi Evgeni. I'm wondering what happened when this plant flowered. Did it turn out to be one of the choices Bamboo had suspected? Might you have a picture of it in bloom you could add here, or at least further information so we can learn what it ended up looking like? Thanks!

Comment: I dont think its the Corn marigold...it does bloom bright yellow, but the flowers are smaller and "tighter" than the pictures for Corn marigold on Google Images, which have way less petals and has these more "spread out". Im sorry for the lack of proper terms, I (obviosly) dont know jack about botany. Unfortunately, I dont have photos of the plant blooming and since its early spring around here, it might be a while till I can take them

Comment: Sounds interesting & pretty even if you're still not sure what it is!  Thanks for the update, it was nice of you to take the time!!

Answer (score 6):

It could be [Corn marigold, *Glebionis segetum*,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glebionis_segetum) judging by the leaves, but ID should be easier once it flowers (which will be yellow, dandelion like ones if it is corn marigold) - it certainly looks like an opportunistic 'weed' plant, in which case, it's very likely to be highly attractive to bees and other insects. It might also, though, be very invasive, as most 'weed' plants are - might be wise to remove spent flowerheads before they turn to seed.

Comment: Thanks! It sure does grow like a weed. It indeed looks like the flowers are going to be yellow, from the buds I opened.

Comment: Just remember, a weed is a plant that is 'out-of-place'...dandelions are considered a weed but someday we might be growing them on purpose in our greenhouses, gardens.  Very valuable, very edible plant...on the other hand most of our exotic weeds were once planted for their beauty...purple loosestrife for example.  And now they are damaging natural ecosystems in a big way (our wetlands, in the case of purple loosestrife).

Comment: @Evgeni Remember you can always mark the correct answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

If it's golden Rod, Eben though many consider them weeds they  have many medicinal benefits and make a nice base to a tea. They are an Anti - Fatigue, not to be confused with stimulant.
Angie Moses

Comment: I'm not sure about identification, on the other hand, you didn't write the scientific name. I recommend that you look in Wikipedia and check the image, to put also the right scientific name. You know: Western Europe used Greek names for western flora, In US they use European names for US flora (and there are also regional differences). In any case: Welcome to the site. The flower bud seems too large, but leaves are very similar. The family it is ok, but I would go in more daisy like flowers.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like saw tooth wild lettuce
 Look it up... we gro it on our homested for meds.
Be careful...

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18525)

Comment: @blackthumb not sure whether the canned message fits here, I see no link?

Comment: see some of the longer explanations on here.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain why the OP needs to be careful, as well as providing a link to more information.